# Path components of finite topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $X,Y$ topological spaces of the same underlying set $\{a,b\}$ and suppose they have the given topologies:  $$T_X:= \{\emptyset, \{a,b\}\},T_Y:=\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\}, \{a,b\}\}$$

Now according to my lecture notes:

> $X$ has one path component and $Y$ has two path components.

I'm a little bit confused on how to determine path components when you have a finite set (actually I'm also confused what would be a "path" in these topologies), how is the computation carried out?

Answer (score 1):

*Every* function from *any* topological space in $X$ is continuous. In particular, the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&X\\&t&\mapsto&\begin{cases}a&\text{ if }t<1\\b&\text {otherwise}\end{cases}\end{array}$$is continuous. It is therefore a path from $a$ to $b$.

But $Y$ is disconnected: the sets $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are nonempty open sets whose union is $Y$ and with empty intersection. So, if $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous and $\gamma(0)=a$, then $\gamma\bigl([0,1]\bigr)=\{a\}$ (since $\gamma\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ is a connected set to which $a$ belongs). So, there is no path from $a$ to $b$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ has the indiscrete topology (meaning the only open subsets are the empty set and the whole space) and $Y$ has the discrete topology (meaning every subset is open). Using only these two facts, you can prove that any function $f : [0,1] \to X$ is continuous, hence you can obtain a path between any two points and you have a path-connected space, and any function $f : [0,1] \to Y$ which is continuous is constant, hence any point is a path component.